# Cue to do posteriorly tilt pelvis for in hip thrust

Tags: glutes

I am watching some hip thrust tutorial, and a cue that is said is to posteriorally tilt the pelvis when donig the movement. For some reason, I can't figure out how to do this. Could someone give me a simple to understand cue to be able to do this?

Comment: Have you  actually tried it yet while doing hip thrusts yet?

Comment: I tried it today. Not sure how well it worked out.. @ThomasMarkov

Comment: A posterior tilt is contracting the glutes to push the hips forward. I believe the glutes are worked more effectively at the shorter range. A posterior tilt would allow you to contract the glutes more thus working them more effectively.